# PyInstaller built my python scripts to executable file, but it doesn't work

Tags: python, pyqt4, pyside, pyinstaller

I am using PyInstaller to create an executable file.

My spec file is as follows:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
import sys

a = Analysis(['maingui.py'],
         hiddenimports=[],
         hookspath=None)
for d in a.datas:
    if 'pyconfig' in d[0]: 
    a.datas.remove(d)
    break
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)
exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      a.binaries,
      a.zipfiles,
      a.datas + [('scheme_1e1s.png', '.\\scheme_1e1s.png', 'DATA')],
      [('scheme_2e1s.png', '.\\scheme_2e1s.png', 'DATA')],
      [('scheme_2e2s.png', '.\\scheme_2e2s.png', 'DATA')],
      [('scheme_2ew1s.png', '.\\scheme_2ew1s.png', 'DATA')],
      [('scheme_3e1s.png', '.\\scheme_3e1s.png', 'DATA')],
      [('scheme_3e1s_inter.png', '.\\scheme_3e1s_inter.png', 'DATA')],
      [('scheme_3e1s_series.png', '.\\scheme_3e1s_series.png', 'DATA')],
      [('scheme_3e2s.png', '.\\scheme_3e2s.png', 'DATA')],
      [('scheme_3e2s_inter.png', '.\\scheme_3e2s_inter.png', 'DATA')],
      [('scheme_3e2s_series.png', '.\\scheme_3e2s_series.png', 'DATA')],
      [('chinese.qm', '.\\chinese.qm', 'DATA')],
      [('spanish.qm', '.\\spanish.qm', 'DATA')],
      name=os.path.join('dist', 'maingui.exe'),
      debug=False,
      strip=None,
      upx=True,
      console=True)

app = BUNDLE(exe,
      name='maingui.exe.app',
      icon=None)
```

And when I run PyInstaller, then it generates exe file to dist successfully.

```
c:\bin\chem>pyinstaller --clean maingui.spec
39 INFO: Testing for ability to set icons, version resources...
72 INFO: ... resource update available
76 INFO: UPX is not available.
101 INFO: Processing hook hook-os
222 INFO: Processing hook hook-time
227 INFO: Processing hook hook-cPickle
300 INFO: Processing hook hook-_sre
434 INFO: Processing hook hook-cStringIO
539 INFO: Processing hook hook-encodings
552 INFO: Processing hook hook-codecs
993 INFO: Removing temporary files and cleaning cache in C:\Users\super2lao\AppData\Roaming\pyinstal
ler
1161 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with c:\bin\chem
1161 INFO: checking Analysis
1161 INFO: building Analysis because out00-Analysis.toc non existent
1161 INFO: running Analysis out00-Analysis.toc
1162 INFO: Adding Microsoft.VC90.CRT to dependent assemblies of final executable
1296 INFO: Searching for assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none ...
1296 INFO: Found manifest C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.
21022.8_none_750b37ff97f4f68b.manifest
1297 INFO: Searching for file msvcr90.dll
1299 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_7
50b37ff97f4f68b\msvcr90.dll
1299 INFO: Searching for file msvcp90.dll
1299 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_7
50b37ff97f4f68b\msvcp90.dll
1299 INFO: Searching for file msvcm90.dll
1299 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_7
50b37ff97f4f68b\msvcm90.dll
1401 INFO: Analyzing c:\bin\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\_pyi_bootstrap.py
1412 INFO: Processing hook hook-os
1428 INFO: Processing hook hook-site
1447 INFO: Processing hook hook-encodings
1570 INFO: Processing hook hook-time
1573 INFO: Processing hook hook-cPickle
1651 INFO: Processing hook hook-_sre
1783 INFO: Processing hook hook-cStringIO
1907 INFO: Processing hook hook-codecs
2370 INFO: Processing hook hook-pydoc
2509 INFO: Processing hook hook-email
2573 INFO: Processing hook hook-httplib
2616 INFO: Processing hook hook-email.message
2684 INFO: Analyzing c:\bin\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py
2736 INFO: Analyzing c:\bin\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_archive.py
2783 INFO: Analyzing c:\bin\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_carchive.py
2832 INFO: Analyzing c:\bin\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_os_path.py
2839 INFO: Analyzing maingui.py
2953 INFO: Processing hook hook-PySide
3226 INFO: Processing hook hook-matplotlib
12008 INFO: Processing hook hook-matplotlib.backends
13428 INFO: Processing hook hook-parser
13579 INFO: Processing hook hook-distutils
14027 INFO: Processing hook hook-setuptools
14319 INFO: Processing hook hook-sysconfig
14351 INFO: Processing hook hook-xml
14416 INFO: Processing hook hook-xml.sax
14450 INFO: Processing hook hook-pyexpat
14529 INFO: Processing hook hook-win32com
14537 INFO: Processing hook hook-win32com.client
14553 INFO: Processing hook hook-pythoncom
14620 INFO: Processing hook hook-pywintypes
14774 INFO: Processing hook hook-win32ui
15550 INFO: Processing hook hook-scipy.sparse.csgraph
16533 INFO: Processing hook hook-PyQt4
16536 INFO: Processing hook hook-PyQt4.QtGui
17297 INFO: Processing hook hook-PyQt4.QtCore
18200 INFO: Hidden import 'codecs' has been found otherwise
18201 INFO: Hidden import 'encodings' has been found otherwise
18201 INFO: Looking for run-time hooks
18203 INFO: Analyzing rthook c:\bin\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_qt
4plugins.py
18247 INFO: Analyzing rthook c:\bin\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_mp
lconfig.py
18304 INFO: Analyzing rthook c:\bin\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_mp
ldata.py
18347 INFO: Analyzing rthook c:\bin\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_pk
gres.py
18494 INFO: Analyzing rthook c:\bin\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_wi
n32comgenpy.py
28392 INFO: Adding Microsoft.VC90.MFC to dependent assemblies of final executable
28521 INFO: Searching for assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.MFC_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none ...
28523 INFO: Found manifest C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\amd64_microsoft.vc90.mfc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0
.21022.8_none_706fccb39ad7e580.manifest
28524 INFO: Searching for file mfc90.dll
28526 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.mfc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_
706fccb39ad7e580\mfc90.dll
28526 INFO: Searching for file mfc90u.dll
28526 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.mfc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_
706fccb39ad7e580\mfc90u.dll
28527 INFO: Searching for file mfcm90.dll
28527 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.mfc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_
706fccb39ad7e580\mfcm90.dll
28534 INFO: Searching for file mfcm90u.dll
28536 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.mfc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_
706fccb39ad7e580\mfcm90u.dll
32259 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
32444 INFO: Using Python library C:\Windows\system32\python27.dll
32641 INFO: Warnings written to c:\bin\chem\build\maingui\warnmaingui.txt
32684 INFO: checking PYZ
32685 INFO: rebuilding out00-PYZ.toc because out00-PYZ.pyz is missing
32686 INFO: building PYZ (ZlibArchive) out00-PYZ.toc
38406 INFO: checking PKG
38407 INFO: rebuilding out00-PKG.toc because out00-PKG.pkg is missing
38407 INFO: building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg
80056 INFO: checking EXE
80057 INFO: building because out00-EXE.toc missing or bad
80059 INFO: building EXE from out00-EXE.toc
80093 INFO: Appending archive to EXE c:\bin\chem\dist\maingui.exe

c:\bin\chem>
```

By the way, I get following error and it is my great difficulty.

```
c:\bin\chem>dist\maingui.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\bin\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_mo
dule
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "c:\bin\chem\build\maingui\out00-PYZ.pyz\PySide", line 41, in <module>
  File "c:\bin\chem\build\maingui\out00-PYZ.pyz\PySide", line 11, in _setupQtDirectories
  File "c:\bin\chem\build\maingui\out00-PYZ.pyz\PySide._utils", line 93, in get_pyside_dir
  File "c:\bin\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 409, in load_mo
dule
    module = imp.load_module(fullname, fp, filename, self._c_ext_tuple)
RuntimeError: the sip module has already registered a module called PyQt4.QtCore

c:\bin\chem>
```

What is wrong?

Comment: I fixed this problem.
There was an error in spec file.
    pyinstaller maingui.py
This command generates a spec file.
I used this, and get a running exe file.

Comment: If you fixed it and it was a simple error or typo, why not deleting the question. It is unlikely it will help anyone else.

Comment: Better not to be deleted, because it shows how to dive in the quest of the error when pyinstaller simply says "Failed to execute the script XXXXX". Now I know that I have to look at these files in addition to ./dist/warn-XXXXX.txt. At a last extent, I am here because I have now that problem, and don't know how to inspect the source of error (for example, it throws "UPX is not available" when running pyinstaller, as in this example, and don't know whether that's important in Win7-64x..)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed this problem. There was an error in spec file. pyinstaller maingui.py This command generates a spec file. I used this, and get a running exe file.

I am glad to fix the issues.

Regards.